# Perl way to run a command taking input from one array and placing output in another array

Tags: perl

For example:

```
# Goal: Take the items in @input_array and sort them using the sort
#       app with the specified flags

# Partial code follows
my @input_array=('abc def 123','ghi jkl 456','mno pqr 789');
my @output_array=`sort -nrk3`; # The data fed to the stdin of sort should be
                              # @input_array with @output_array getting the sorted output
                              # per the command with the given flags

# Sure, we can dump @input_array to a temp file and use that as the input for sort, but
# I am hoping to avoid this.
```

Comment: [sort](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## perl - map array into array using external program (e.g. sort)

"Pure perl" solution is better for sample data included in the question
**but** some people will need (re)map by an external program.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use IPC::Run;

sub sortie {
  my ( $cmd, @input_array ) = @_;
  my $in = join( "\n", @input_array, '' );
  IPC::Run::run $cmd, \$in, \my $out, \my $err;
  return $out =~ /^(.*)$/mg;
} ## end sub sortie

my @input_array = ( 'abc def 123', 'ghi jkl 456', 'mno pqr 789' );
my @output_array = sortie( [ 'sort', '-nrk3' ], @input_array );
print "$_\n" for @output_array;
```

Comment: Under what circumstances is this better than using Perl's `sort` function?

Comment: Functionality of specific external sort program may be too hard/costly/timely to implement in perl (e.g. some complicated queries of some proprietary databases).  AFAIK perl had started as a "scripting glue" language. BTW Pure perl implementation of the sample sort given as example is **trivial**.

Comment: In what circumstances does keeping, at the very least, a copy of the original array, a copy of its stringified version, a stringified copy of the sorted version, and a copy of the sorted array in the memory of the Perl process going to help anything? If your data set is trivial enough that you can utilize the external `sort` the way you did, you are far better off using Perl's sort. If not, this is not going to improve the situation. Also, AFAIK, the `sort` utility does not query any external databases. That would be kinda weird. The OP is misguided and this answer enforces the OP's mistake.

Comment: @SinanÜnür Anyway such recipe may be used not only for sorting.

Comment: @SinanÜnür You seem to treat "sample task" as the real problem to solve. I have treated it as a trivial "task for tests".

Comment: "**Goal: Take the items in `@input_array` and sort them using the `sort`**" ... I can easily imagine situations in which it is better to delegate sorting to an external utility. I can't imagine how doing it this way would help. But, to each his own, I guess.

Comment: @Andrzej, thank you for defending your answer and as a result, the original question. The problem presented was a simple example and not at all the actual problem I am trying to solve. It is really too bad that people often read (way) too much into the simple easy to understand examples that are provided to present real world problems on this site. Hopefully my upvote along with the acceptance of your answer, can compensate for any undeserved downvotes you received for trying to be helpful while not being judgmental and narrow-minded as to the actual problem I am trying to solve.

Answer (score 3):

```
my @output_array = sort { (split(' ', $b))[2] <=> (split(' ', $a))[2] } @input_array;
```

or

```
use Sort::Key qw( rnkeysort );

my @output_array = rnkeysort { (split)[2] } @input_array;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# custom comparison function for sort
sub sortie {
  # map input data $a, $b into data for comparison $A, $B (trailing numbers)
  my($A,$B) = map { /\s(\d+)$/ } ($a,$b);
  # compare $A and $B numerically returning reverse order
  # compare $a and $b string as fall-back (when $A and $B are equal)   
  return $B <=> $A || $a cmp $b;
}

# data/array to be sorted
my @input_array=('abc def 123','ghi jkl 456','mno pqr 789');
# sort array using sortie for comparison
my @output_array = sort sortie @input_array; 

# print/show sorted array
print "$_\n" for @output_array;
```